# jdbc/mysql ---> java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

I need make a connection between java web and mysql, I am using netbeans but I don't know how.

If I dont write the password I have this fail but if I write the password, the failure is `java.sql.SQLException: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigInteger cannot be cast to java.lang.Long`

I need help with my code!, this is my code, I am using netbeans!

```
package conexion;
import java.sql.*;

public class CONEXION_BD {
    public static Connection getConexion(){
        Connection con=null;
        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con=DriverManager.getConnection
                ("jdbc:mysql://localhost/bd_prueba?user=root&password=");

            System.out.println("Conexion ok");
        }catch(ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e){
            System.out.println("Error "+e);
        }
        return con;
    }

    public static void main (String[] args){
        CONEXION_BD.getConexion();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and write in english

Comment: @Anair Terán looks like the password value  is missing in the declaration.

Comment: @PritamBanerjee

I need make a connection beetwen java web and mysql, i am using netbeans but i dont kwon how.

if i dont write the password i have this fail but if write the password the fail is "java.sql.SQLException: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigInteger cannot be cast to java.lang.Long" 

*maybe i have fail wrinting in english, sorry, my english is basic! *

Comment: Try this with proper user name and password `Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(  
                "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql","root","password");`

Comment: Can you share the full and exact error message? Usually, Java errors contain a stactrace that helps to locate the problem

Comment: Upgrade your version of MySQL Connector/J.

Answer (score 0):

You should add this in MySQL to make sure that the user has the correct permissions:

```
CREATE USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

And then GRANT ALL permissions:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'root'@'localhost';
```

And then you can use DriverConnection like this and make sure that you have the username and password added correctly:

```
 Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(  
                "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql","root","password");
```

Comment: Please share some explanation such that others can learn from your answer - which exact part makes the difference?

Answer (score 0):

Is the reason for not claiming the port?

Or reset your database user information, it is recommended that you set a password to try, you have no problem with this code, please confirm the database status

```
package conexion;
import java.sql.*;

public class CONEXION_BD {
    public static Connection getConexion(){
        Connection con=null;
        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con=DriverManager.getConnection
                ("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bd_prueba?user=root&password=");

            System.out.println("Conexion ok");
        }catch(ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e){
            System.out.println("Error "+e);
        }
        return con;
    }

    public static void main (String[] args){
        CONEXION_BD.getConexion();
    }
}
```

Comment: hi but no

I have the same error !